# What does 'Poco Meno' mean?

Tags: terminology, double-bass

I am currently studying Simandl's 30 Studies for String Bass, and on the 6th one I came upon this term:

[image]

Since I'm not acquainted with Italian Musical Terms, I used [this site](http://www.musictheory.org.uk/res-musical-terms/italian-musical-terms.php) to find out what `Poco Meno` means.

`poco   ->  a little`
`meno   ->  less`

But I'm not sure what that is supposed to mean. A little less what?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally it is to do with speed/tempo. Poco= a little, meno = less, so, a teensy bit slower. Slower than marked, or slower than you played the bit before. Often followed by 'mosso'.

Comment: "Generally it is to do with tempo": furthermore, in this case it is clearly printed in the position and typeface of a tempo indication.

Comment: Not sure I understand the comment. The legend may also indicate *how* the piece is played, not merely what its tempo is. And often, the wording gives a lot of leeway to tempo.

Comment: I understood @phoog's comment immediately: in the "classical" piano music I play, that physical location of the words, as well as fontsize, absolutely say "tempo comment/marking" to me. :)

Answer (score 2):

Not as a musician, which I am even though not on this kind of stuff unfortunately, but as a translator, even though usually the way round en-it, what I get from it in Italian is that you should do a little less than what they prompted you to do earlier, whatever it was; maybe a forte or such; but not too much less, just a little. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In my edition of Harriet Cohen's transcription of Bach's 'Ertödt uns durch dein' Gute' the phrase 'meno' appears regularly, on its own. I think it means 'less' of the previous crescendos, Fortes etc. in the previous passages i.e. a return to normal tempo and loudness.

Comment: This would be true if not for the fact that the instruction appears above the staff in the position and graphical style of a tempo indication.  If it were related to dynamics it would be below the staff and in the same typeface as _pesante._

Comment: Again, I agree with @phoog on this...

Answer (score 1):

From Harvard Dictionary of Music 2nd Edition (Apel)

Meno (It.): less
Poco: (It.): little

'Poco meno' is ambiguous. I saw the expression in 'Glass The Piano Collection' too.

Answer (score 0):

"Poco meno" is ambiguous.  A little less what indeed?  As it's combined with "pesante" and a "f" dynamic (what was the preceding dynamic?) we can guess it's not asking for a smaller sound.  Probably a little less speed.  Watch the conductor and see what HE thinks it means!

Comment: It's a study for string bass. Conductor?